# Why could differ functionality of pre and post-compiled script that works with file system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, auto-py-to-exe

For this program i use Python 3.10, PyCharm, and PyQt5

There is a program that takes an excel file and converts it to .csv: each sheet into the separate file using Pandas.

The file can be taken from any directory, but the output file is always in the directory of the project.
Before the writing, the program checks if a file with the same name aleady exists:

```
if os.path.isfile(f'{duplicate_name}{cur_sheet_name}.csv'):
# duplicate_name contains path to the directory
```

So if there is a duplicate file, the program adds name of input file to the name of the output file. *(I assume it should check if the file in the input directory, but still it writes and checks in the project' directory for some reason)*

**The thing is** that the program checks for duplicates when I run it from IDE, but when I compile it using auto-py-to-exe — it doesn't checks for duplicates and simply over-writes the existing file.

It is a function that is imported to the main.py when called.

[full code of the function](https://github.com/Crowdedn/excel_to_bd/blob/main/bd_convert.py)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a file's path to the writing cycle, question closed